# Add jQuery to a CSS Dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, navigation, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS based menu and I want to add a Slide down easing effect (easeOutBounce) to it. Here is my Script, HTML and an image for reference. I want to add this easing effect to a css class named `".fusion-submenu-wrapper"`

I am loading `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` & `jquery.easing.1.3.min.js` in my template. The Menu title is animating but the the easing effect is not being applied to the drop-down.

Kindly Help

```
// Mega Menu
$(function() {

    var $menu = $('#jompress_menu');

    $menu.children('li.parent').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $span = $this.children('span');
        $span.data('width',$span.width());

        $this.bind('mouseenter',function(){
            $menu.find('.slider').stop(true,true).hide();
            $span.stop().animate({'width':'335px'},'200'function(){
                $this.find('.slider').slideDown();
            });
        }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
            $this.find('.slider').stop(true,true).hide();
            $span.stop().animate({'width':$span.data('width')+'px'},'200');
        });
    });
});
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<!-- Begin Top Navigation -->

<div id="jompressMenu" class="nav nav-main">
    <div class="nopill">
        <ul id="jompress_menu" class="menutop level1 slider " >
            <li class="item1 active root" > <a class="orphan item image subtext" href="http://localhost/svr/jom/"  > <span>
                <div class="menu-image"> <img src="/svr/jom/templates/jompress_j15/images/icons/64x64/Home.png" alt="Home.png" /> </div>
                <div class="menu-text">
                    <div class="menu-maintext"> Home </div>
                    <div class="menu-subtext"> <em>My Place</em> </div>
                </div>
                </span> </a> </li>
            <li class="item61 parent root" > <span class="daddy item image subtext nolink slider"> <span>
                <div class="menu-image"> <img src="/svr/jom/templates/jompress_j15/images/icons/64x64/Web.png" alt="Web.png" /> </div>
                <div class="menu-text">
                    <div class="menu-maintext"> Demo <em>In Action</em> </div>
                </div>
                </span> </span>
                <div class="fusion-submenu-wrapper slider level2" style="width:180px;">
                    <ul class="level2" style="width:180px;">
                        <li class="item64" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/"  > <span>
                            <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                            <div class="menu-text">
                                <div class="menu-maintext"> Example Menu </div>
                                <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                            </div>
                            </span> </a> </li>
                        <li class="item54 parent" > <a class="daddy item bullet" href="/svr/jom/"  > <span>
                            <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                            <div class="menu-text">
                                <div class="menu-maintext"> Module in Menu </div>
                                <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                            </div>
                            </span> </a>
                            <div class="fusion-submenu-wrapper slider level3 columns3" style="width:600px;">
                                <ul class="level3" style="width:200px;">
                                    <li class="item27 parent grouped-parent" > <a class="daddy item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=19&amp;Itemid=27"  > <span>
                                        <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                        <div class="menu-text">
                                            <div class="menu-maintext"> Joomla! Overview </div>
                                            <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </span> </a>
                                        <div class="fusion-grouped ">
                                            <ol>
                                                <li class="item34" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=22&amp;Itemid=34"  > <span>
                                                    <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                                    <div class="menu-text">
                                                        <div class="menu-maintext"> What&#039;s New in 1.5? </div>
                                                        <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </span> </a> </li>
                                                <li class="item2" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=5&amp;Itemid=2"  > <span>
                                                    <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                                    <div class="menu-text">
                                                        <div class="menu-maintext"> Joomla! License </div>
                                                        <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </span> </a> </li>
                                                <li class="item37 parent" > <a class="daddy item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=section&amp;id=4&amp;Itemid=37"  > <span>
                                                    <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                                    <div class="menu-text">
                                                        <div class="menu-maintext"> More about Joomla! </div>
                                                        <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </span> </a>
                                                    <div class="fusion-submenu-wrapper slider level5" style="width:180px;">
                                                        <ul class="level5" style="width:180px;">
                                                            <li class="item41" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=section&amp;id=3&amp;Itemid=41"  > <span>
                                                                <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                                                <div class="menu-text">
                                                                    <div class="menu-maintext"> FAQ </div>
                                                                    <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </span> </a> </li>
                                                            <li class="item50" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=1&amp;Itemid=50"  > <span>
                                                                <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                                                <div class="menu-text">
                                                                    <div class="menu-maintext"> The News </div>
                                                                    <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </span> </a> </li>
                                                            <li class="item48" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_weblinks&amp;view=categories&amp;Itemid=48"  > <span>
                                                                <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                                                <div class="menu-text">
                                                                    <div class="menu-maintext"> Web Links </div>
                                                                    <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </span> </a> </li>
                                                            <li class="item49" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_newsfeeds&amp;view=categories&amp;Itemid=49"  > <span>
                                                                <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                                                <div class="menu-text">
                                                                    <div class="menu-maintext"> News Feeds </div>
                                                                    <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                </span> </a> </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        <div class="drop-bot"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="level3" style="width:200px;">
                                    <li class="item56 grouped-parent" > <span class="orphan item bullet nolink slider"> <span>
                                        <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                        <div class="menu-text">
                                            <div class="menu-maintext"> Login </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </span> </span>
                                        <div class="fusion-grouped  type-module">
                                            <ol>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="fusion-modules item">
                                                        <form action="/svr/jom/index.php" method="post" name="login" id="form-login" >
                                                            <fieldset class="input">
                                                                <p id="form-login-username">
                                                                    <label for="modlgn_username">Username</label>
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    <input id="modlgn_username" type="text" name="username" class="inputbox" alt="username" size="18" />
                                                                </p>
                                                                <p id="form-login-password">
                                                                    <label for="modlgn_passwd">Password</label>
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    <input id="modlgn_passwd" type="password" name="passwd" class="inputbox" size="18" alt="password" />
                                                                </p>
                                                                <p id="form-login-remember">
                                                                    <label for="modlgn_remember">Remember Me</label>
                                                                    <input id="modlgn_remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes" alt="Remember Me" />
                                                                </p>
                                                                <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Login" />
                                                            </fieldset>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li> <a href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_user&amp;view=reset"> Forgot your password?</a> </li>
                                                                <li> <a href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_user&amp;view=remind"> Forgot your username?</a> </li>
                                                                <li> <a href="/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_user&amp;view=register"> Create an account</a> </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_user" />
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="login" />
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="L3N2ci9qb20v" />
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="d833143a0d618ec33f3663f5cad4a48c" value="1" />
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="level3" style="width:200px;">
                                    <li class="item60 grouped-parent" > <span class="orphan item bullet nolink slider"> <span>
                                        <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                                        <div class="menu-text">
                                            <div class="menu-maintext"> Opinion Poll </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </span> </span>
                                        <div class="fusion-grouped  type-module">
                                            <ol>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="fusion-modules item">
                                                        <div class="module-poll ">
                                                            <form action="index.php" method="post" name="form2">
                                                                <h4>Joomla! is used for?</h4>
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="voteid1" value="1" alt="1" />
                                                                        <label for="voteid1">Community Sites</label>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="voteid2" value="2" alt="2" />
                                                                        <label for="voteid2">Public Brand Sites</label>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="voteid3" value="3" alt="3" />
                                                                        <label for="voteid3">eCommerce</label>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="voteid4" value="4" alt="4" />
                                                                        <label for="voteid4">Blogs</label>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="voteid5" value="5" alt="5" />
                                                                        <label for="voteid5">Intranets</label>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="voteid6" value="6" alt="6" />
                                                                        <label for="voteid6">Photo and Media Sites</label>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="voteid7" value="7" alt="7" />
                                                                        <label for="voteid7">All of the Above!</label>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                                <p class="buttons">
                                                                    <input type="submit" name="task_button" class="button-vote" value="Vote" />
                                                                    <input type="button" name="option" class="button-results" value="Results" onclick="document.location.href='/svr/jom/index.php?option=com_poll&amp;id=14:joomla-is-used-for'" />
                                                                </p>
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_poll" />
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="vote" />
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14" />
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="d833143a0d618ec33f3663f5cad4a48c" value="1" />
                                                            </form>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="drop-bot"></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item69" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/"  > <span>
                            <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                            <div class="menu-text">
                                <div class="menu-maintext"> Example Menu </div>
                                <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                            </div>
                            </span> </a> </li>
                        <li class="item70" > <a class="orphan item bullet" href="/svr/jom/"  > <span>
                            <div class="menu-image"> </div>
                            <div class="menu-text">
                                <div class="menu-maintext"> Example Menu </div>
                                <div class="menu-subtext"> </div>
                            </div>
                            </span> </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="drop-bot"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item55 root" > <a class="orphan item image subtext" href="/svr/jom/"  > <span>
                <div class="menu-image"> <img src="/svr/jom/templates/jompress_j15/images/icons/64x64/Help.png" alt="Help.png" /> </div>
                <div class="menu-text">
                    <div class="menu-maintext"> Help </div>
                    <div class="menu-subtext"> <em>Support</em> </div>
                </div>
                </span> </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Top Navigation -->
```

**Here is the link to image for Menu :**

[Reference Image of the menu](http://iamonline.in/megamenu.jpg)

Comment: Probably advisable to show the HTML in question too.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, please see the new edited version with HTML, Javascript and a link to the reference image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to `animate()` is the easing, which you haven't added. Also, you've got a syntax error:

```
 $span.stop().animate({'width':'335px'},'200'function(){
                $this.find('.slider').slideDown();
            });
```

should read

```
 $span.stop().animate({'width':'335px'},'200', 'bounce', function(){
                $this.find('.slider').slideDown();
            });
```

Change `'bounce'` to whatever the easing effect is that you want, and that should do it.